# ¿ Cómo separar un Array por un valor determinado en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tengo este array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://dominio1.com
    [1] => https://dominio2.com
    [2] => https://dominio3.com
    [3] => <--<separador>-->
    [4] => https://dominio4.com
    [5] => https://dominio5.com
    [6] => <--<separador>-->
    [7] => https://dominio6.com
    [8] => https://dominio7.com
    [9] => https://dominio8.com
)
```

Y me gustaría separarlo en tres por cada valor que ponga `<--<separador>-->`, he intentado hacerlo con `explode` pero no funciona, ya que es un valor del `array`. No tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

¿ Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar `explode` como tenía pensado pero antes deberá convertir el array a un `String` con la función [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

```
$array = array('https://dominio1.com','https://dominio2.com','https://dominio3.com',
            '<--<separador>-->',
            'https://dominio4.com','https://dominio5.com',
            '<--<separador>-->',
     'https://dominio6.com','https://dominio7.com','https://dominio8.com');

$new = explode('<--<separador>-->', json_encode($array));

print_r($new);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/DFCA49268)</kbd>

Comment: Que bien visto, me gusta tu idea +1